# HTML code- the output is not what i want

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
 <body>
  <form action= "http://norton.open.ac.uk/reflect.php" method= "post" name= "form1">
      <h1> Book Details: </h1>
     <select name= "dropdown">
        <option value= "Books" selected>Books</option>
        <option value= "Magazines">Magazines</option>
        <option value= "Journals">Journals</option>
        <option value= "Newspapers">Newspapers</option>

     <p>
     <b>Book name:</b>  <input type = "text" name = "book_name" /> </p>
     <p>
     <b>Author:</b>  <input type = "text" name = "author" /> </p>
     <p>
     <b>Publication Year:</b>  <input type = "date" name = "publication_year" /> </p>
     <p>
     <b>ISBN Number:</b>  <input type = "number" name = "isbn_number" /> </p>

     <input type= "submit" name= "submit" value= "Submit" />
   </form>
```

I'm pretty sure something is wrong with the code, I just can't pinpoint what exactly it is. The output is not what I want.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: *"The output is not what I want."* - What output **do** you want?

Comment: You have not closed the select field after defining options i.e </select>

Comment: You've missed `</select>` behind your `<option ..>`'s

Comment: Don't name a form control "submit", or any other name that matches a standard form property as it masks the property. Why the *javascript* tag when there is no javascript?

Comment: It looks like you are missing the select and body close tags.

Comment: Better to add the expected output and provide the details as much as you can.

Comment: `The output is not what I want.` is up there with `it doesn't work` as far as problem description goes

Comment: @RobG there is no property on an HTML input element called "submit" to be masked, and even if there was, `type`, `name` and `value` do not override properties. I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: @NickCoad—no, but there's a standard **form** property named submit (it's the submit method) and it does override the form's submit property, since named controls are added as named properties of the form. Try `<form><input type="button" name="submit" onclick="this.form.submit()" value="Submit form"></form>`. It will fail as `this.form.submit` refers to the button, not the method. Change the button name to anything else (or remove it) and it works. ;-)

Comment: @RobG well spotted, I learned something today!

Answer (score 1):

So there are a couple of things that you will need to do to get this to work...

```
<input type="submit" />
```

you could use an id if you need to set some sort of submit in JS.

not sure 100% what you have going here but your form could look something like this:

```
<form action="http://norton.open.ac.uk/reflect.php" id="form1">
    <div>
        <label for="book">Book Name:</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="author">Author:</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="publication">Publication Year:</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="isbn">ISBN Number:</label>
        <input type="number">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Make sure your values inside HTML element tags are: `type=""` vs. what is in your current state `type= ""`. no need for spaces in between.

Also, for future reference please state a little more about what you are trying to accomplish. If you are submitting a form like this and you are using JS please specify what the current output is and what your desired output would be. It could also help if you supplied some research you have done to solve the problem.

Hope this helps you out!